# AngularJS $rootScope function ng-change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

**html**

```
<input type="text" data-search="type" placeholder="Search a Candidate, Job, Certificate or Location" ng-model="searchMain" ng-change="$root.updateSearchField(searchMain)"/>
```

Above is an input field that will act as a realtime search, this is put into `index.html` and using `Angular-Route` I am using routing for the pages to load in.

**Angular**

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $templateCache) {

        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
            console.log(current);
            if (typeof(current) !== 'undefined'){
                $templateCache.remove(current.templateUrl);
            }
        });

        $scope.filterText = '';
        // Instantiate these variables outside the watch
        var tempFilterText = '', filterTextTimeout;
        $rootScope.updateSearchField = function(foo) {
            console.log($scope.searchMain);
            if (filterTextTimeout) $timeout.cancel(filterTextTimeout);
            tempFilterText = foo;
            filterTextTimeout = $timeout(function() {
                $rootScope.searchText = tempFilterText;
                console.log($rootScope.searchText);
            }, 250); // delay 250 ms
        };

    });
```

The function for the `ng-change()` I've seen should be inside `.run()` and yet when I key up there is still no `console.log()` return.

How would I be able to run an `ng-change` or ng-click`from the`$rootScope`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-change` accepts a parameter, which is an expression. Once the value of the input changes the expression will be **evaluated in the context of the current scope**. This means that if the scope associated with the current element (or any other of its parent scopes), doesn't has `$rootScope` property, your snippet is **not** going to work.

Try something like this instead:

```
<input type="text" data-search="type" placeholder="Search a Candidate, Job, Certificate or Location" ng-model="searchMain" ng-change="updateSearchField()"/>
```

Comment: When I start typing, it still doesn't fire anything